# Regex to identify MQTT topics

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get a regex in C# to parse an mqtt topic to know which action to perform for each topic type we defined in our system. We have two topics that must be differentiated:

1. cd/hl/projects/{project_id}/var/{var_name}
2. cd/hl/projects/{project_id}/var/{var_name}/write

{project_id} can be any character but a line break (\n). Can be empty
{var_name} can be any character but a line break (\n). Can be empty

to match string 2 I use the following and it's working in all cases i tested:

```
    ^cd/hl/projects/.*/var/.*/write$
```

So far so good. But I fail when I try to match 1. without also giving a match on 2. using the following regexs:

```
    ^(cd/hl/projects/.*/var/.*)(?!/write)$

    what I think should do (but it doesn't):
    (cd/hl/projects/.*/var/.*)  #match any projects and var_names
    (?!/write)                  #not match if /write appears
```

The problem is that I can't stop matching strings that have /write in the end like:

```
    cd/hl/projects/4d69439d-8c13-4e83-9ed5-60659d953f9f/var/test_count_one/write
```

I just want not to match the string above but only with:

```
    cd/hl/projects/{project_id}/var/{var_name}
```

My questions are: I'm following the right approach? What am I missing? How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^/]*`. They cannot also contain `/`, not just `\n`.

Comment: Женя, do you need to write two different patterns or one? Please clarify.

Comment: one pattern for each topic. each pattern should match only for his own topic. So I need two different patterns

Comment: Ok, 1) `^cd/hl/projects/([^/]*)/var/([^/]*)` and 2) `^cd/hl/projects/([^/]*)/var/([^/]*)/write$` - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subparts should contain no `/`, not just `\n`. You should replace `.*` with `[^/\n]*` and use

```
REGEX 1: ^cd/hl/projects/([^/\n]*)/var/([^/\n]*)
REGEX 2: ^cd/hl/projects/([^/\n]*)/var/([^/\n]*)/write$
```

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/E0WDBZ/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/E0WDBZ/2).

The `[^/\n]*` [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matches any 0+ (due to `*`) chars other than `/` and `\n`.